# Why does SAGA plugin "Channel Network and Drainage Basins" fail with the addition of one specific DEM tile?

Tags: qgis, saga, watershed

I am working on developing a stream network and watershed layer in QGIS. I have 1047 DEM tiles I downloaded from NC (https://sdd.nc.gov/). When I try to run the plugins on the entire set (see attached screenshots), the channels plugin fails (SAGA-->Terrain Analysis - Channels-->Channel Network and Drainage Basins). I spent a lot of time systematically narrowing down the offending tile that is D10_37_00889114_20190331.tif.

With this one tile removed the channel plugin runs, but the subsequent watersheds are not correct because this tile includes a junction point in the stream network.

I have attached a few screenshots with the two SAGA plugins circled that I am using.

What should I try next?

Note I am using QGIS version 3.16.3-Hannover because the newer SAGA plugins are broken in higher versions.

Here's the computer I am working with:

Edition Windows 10 Home
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎6/‎16/‎2021
OS build    19045.3930
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19053.1000.0

Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4600U CPU @ 2.10GHz   2.70 GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Here is the error message I get:

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/heath/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_pwoQjH/0f552578c4684df4a618faeec4ce9088/ORDER.sdat
• C:/Users/heath/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_pwoQjH/339f20baa19847f3977d99dd02244538/ORDER.sdat
• C:/Users/heath/Desktop/Laurel_Watershed/Laurel_v1-8-008881/channels.shp
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

[image: tiles]
[image: filled DEMs]
[image: channels]

Comment: Kindly edit the post to add the error message rather mentioning it in a comment.

Comment: In doing similar work using Maine tiled DEMs from LiDAR, I found 2 or 3 tiles that were faulty.  I reported these but if they were fixed it was after my work was done.  I had downloaded the LiDAR point data for other purposes, and so I created a DEM for the missing tiles from that data and used it.  So my suggestion is to look at the problem tile and see if you can determine if it is faulty, report it to the provider and if you have access to the original LiDAR (hopefully classified) make your own.

Comment: @John, I am able to run a small set of only 6 tiles with that offending tile included, but when it is in the larger set of 1047 tiles it fails. See image attached.

Comment: ![small set of 6 tiles](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ri-wv5JLUHMlWaIcMYMjVoELVPtN325K/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The SAGA plugins aren't "broken" - you just need the new version (SAGA Next Gen) for the new QGIS versions.

Comment: Which tool is failing - is it one or both?

Comment: I would still download that tile again; check it and then I'd merge the tiles into a single DEM and run the SAGA tools on that.

Comment: @John When I check it, what am I looking for?

Comment: @TomBrennan Only the "Channel Network and Drainage Basins" tool fails. "Fill Sinks (Wang & Liu)" seems to work fine.

Comment: What steps are you currently doing before you run the "Channel Network and Drainage Basins" (and it failing), and what inputs are you using to the channel network tool? I'd suggest updating the question.  I did go to the website to see if I could get the tiles myself but the website appears to be down. I used to use Fill Sinks to prepare data for Channel Networks, but I tend to use Breach Depressions from Whitebox Tools these days.

Comment: I have tried both merging the tiles into an new tif or using a virtual raster before running fill sinks. I have tried a range of values in fill sinks before channels and nothing seems to work. I have even investigated the difference between the fill sinks output and the original, but nothing pops out as a problem. Recently, I redownloaded the offending tile thinking it might be corrupted, but that did not work either. What is strange is it runs with the offending tile in a reduced data set of only six tiles so it seems that the tile is not corrupted.

Comment: I can't access the tiles, so hard to diagnose. I would suggest trying Whitebox Tools and Breach Depressions